# What's the difference between [CustomStruct()] and [CustomStruct]()?

Tags: swift, xcode, struct

In swift, what's the difference between :

```
var myStruct = [CustomStruct()]
```

and

```
var myStruct2 = [CustomStruct]()
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: What about replacing `()` with `.init()`, does it make it more readable? This way you won't see `[` vs `(`?: `let myStruct = [CustomStruct.init()]; `let myStruct2 = [CustomStruct].init()`. Do you see where is applied the "init", on what? Note that printing them might help you too.

Comment: What about trying yourself in a playground, print and see what else you can do with the different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myStruct = [CustomStruct()]
```

> declares an array with 1 object `CustomStruct()`

```
let myStruct2 = [CustomStruct]()
```

> declares an immutable empty array

Comment: It should be with VAR instead of LET, I edited my question